# pausing a child process and resuming it from the parent

Tags: c, forms, signals, kill, pause

Got almost no clue how signals work, besides the theory of it. I'm writing a programm that needs for the child process to start, pause, wait for the parent process to send a signal, then the parent process does its thing running its part of the code, sends a signal, waits for the child to finish, the child then resumes and continues past the pause(); and finishes so the parent can continue so it can finish as well.
I've tried doing kill(c_pid, SIGCONT), but the program just hangs cause the child process never unpauses and the parent is waiting for the child to finish.
Do i need to put a void fuction that does something to check the signal, write someone before the pause(); ?

Comment: I'm confused by *"wait for the parent process to start"* - what started this "child" process besides a parent process that by-definition must already be running? Or did you mean "wait for the parent process to *resume*" ?

Comment: @WhozCraig my bad, i meant waits for the parent process to send the signal for it to resume. I've edited the post to be worded better.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

> the child process never unpauses and the parent is waiting for the child to finish. Do i need to put a void fuction that does something to check the signal, write someone before the pause(); ?

According to its docs, [`pause()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pause.2.html)

> causes the calling process (or thread) to sleep until a signal is delivered **that either terminates the process or causes the invocation of a signal-catching function**.

(Emphasis added.)

So yes, if you want the child to resume from a `pause()` then you must ensure that the receipt of the parent's signal causes a signal-catching function (a.k.a. a "signal handler") to be called.  That requires registering such a handler for that signal via the `signal()` or (better) `sigaction()` function before `pause()`ing.  The signature of a signal handler would be `void some_name(int)`, so probably that's what you were thinking of.